# IE8 JavaScript Form Submit Fails on File Field when Name is Set

Tags: javascript, html, forms, internet-explorer-8

Please note the code below. Clicking on the upload button should open a file selection dialog, and once a file is selected, the form should automatically submit to the (non-existent) script.  This was done to allow control of the upload from an unrelated control, outside of the form.

This works in Chrome and FireFox, but not in IE8.  Additionally, the offending line is the name of the upload field (name="uploadName").  If I remove that, everything works in IE8, but then I can't access the uploaded file from the script.  Doing this manually (via the Browse button) works in all environments.

Any suggestions for a work-around?

Here's the sample code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="idFrmUpload">
            <input id="uploadID"   type="file"   name="uploadName" onchange="document.myForm.submit();" />
            <input type="submit" />
       </form>
       <p />
       <button onclick="document.getElementById('uploadID').click();">Upload</button>       
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046928/file-upload-ie8-inputtype-file-filled-in-by-triggering-with-javascript-empt), did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Sadly I found no solution :(.